# Position of pinned nav [jquery.pin.js]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for some help with the position of my nav. I'm using the jquery.pin.js script to make it sticked within a container. That works.

But I would like to attribute a top at 50% of the windows when scrolling on the container and not just a padding value. Something like that :

```
 top:50%;margin-top:-40px;//half of nav height
```

A basic Fiddle here without top value : http://jsfiddle.net/vdqfvqh5/

An image of the nav behavior if it's helped : [link (to dropbox)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10351694/pinned_nav.jpg)

Thanks a lot for helping !

Comment: I don't understand where you want to add `top:50%`. Can you try to add it to your fiddle?

Comment: Hi Dura, right now, I don't know how to add it; it was just to illustrated the position I'm looking for the nav. I'm even not sure it's possible to do this type of css using the pin jquery script...